# ParserError: Expected identifier but got 'contract'

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Getting Error while working on solidity for TRC20 Token Cretaion

ParserError: Expected identifier but got 'contract'

CODE

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4; MIT

contract TRC20 {
        
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    unit8 public decimals = 8;
    unit256 public totalsupply;
    
    mapping (address => unit256) public balanc0f;
    mapping (address => mapping(address=>unit256)) public allowance;
    
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, unit256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, unit256 value);
    event Burn(address indexed from, unit256 value);
```

Comment: Please post the code (at least the beginning of it)

Comment: contract TRC20 {
        
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    unit8 public decimals = 8;
    unit256 public totalsupply;
    
    mapping (address => unit256) public balanc0f;
    mapping (address => mapping(address=>unit256)) public allowance;
    
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, unit256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, unit256 value);
    event Burn(address indexed from, unit256 value);

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra word "MIT" there. Just remove that.

If you want to indicate the contract's licensing mode, you can add something like this as the first line:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
```

Have a look here for the complete styling guide: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.0/style-guide.html

Comment: Now i am getting Error:   unit8 public decimals = 18;  

DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique.
--> TRC TEST.sol:8:5:
|
8 | unit8 public decimals = 18;

Comment: it should be `uint` instead of `unit`. Please try to be more careful and try to solve the problems yourself first. If you have further questions, please post a new question

Answer (score 1):

Remove MIT from pragma `solidity ^0.8.4; MIT`
and add a closing bracket

Comment: If i remove MIT then i got another error


Warning: SPDX license identifier not provided in source file. Before publishing, consider adding a comment containing "SPDX-License-Identifier: <SPDX-License>" to each source file. Use "SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED" for non-open-source code. Please see https://spdx.org for more information.

Comment: 7 | unit8 public decimals = 18;
| ^^^^^
string public name;
    string public symbol;
    unit8 public decimals = 18;
    unit256 public totalsupply;

Comment: for the license part you can use : // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT